# Swipe command in calabash iOS

Tags: ruby, calabash, swipeview, calabash-ios

Hi i have to swipe the bunch of screens and i tried some of the syntax like

```
scroll("*",:right)
swipe "left", {:query => "*"}
swipe(:left)
```

But it swipes and leave back the screen to same screen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the "[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" documentation, along with the related links at the bottom of that page.

Comment: what are the details 
calabash-ios gem version?
iOS simulator version?

Answer (score 2):

There are several known bugs in Apple's UIAutomation API.  Swiping on simulators has been broken on iOS Simulators since iOS 7. [1](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/253)

You *might* be able to work around this bug by tightening up your query.  Instead of using "*", refine your query to match the scroll view you want to swipe on.

```
swipe "left", {:query => "UIScrollView marked:'some identifying mark'"}
swipe :right, {:query => "UIScrollView index:0"}
```

There are many cases where scroll views are embedded in other scroll views.  In that case you might need to hunt around for the scroll view that *will* respond to the swipe.

As an aside, I do not recommend using the "*" wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

No one of the answers here worked for me.

Give a try to the pan method:
http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/ios/Calabash/Cucumber/Core.html#pan-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub for calabash-ios suggest

> Swiping an unspecified place (usually when you have big scroll view in
>   the center of the screen). Swipe directions can be left, right, up and
>   down.
>
> `Then I swipe left`

[GitHub Calabash-iOS Predefines steps](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/02-Predefined-steps)